# How to use "<!--{if $smarty.get" on tpl file to get some words on url

Tags: url, if-statement, smarty

On a tpl file(header.tpl) I would like to write a code that will change button (each contains different link) which will be dependent on several different url setting. For example,

```
example.com/usa.php
example.com/uk.php
example.com

header.tpl
<!--▼HEADER-->
<!--{if $smarty.get.page == "usa"}-->
<a href="<!--{$smarty.const.HTTPS_URL}-->baseball.php" ><img src="baseball_button" ></a>

<!--{else}--><!--{if $smarty.get.page == "uk"}-->
<a href="<!--{$smarty.const.HTTPS_URL}-->soccer.php" ><img src="soccer_button" ></a>
<!--{else}--> 
<a href="<!--{$smarty.const.HTTPS_URL}-->sumo.php" ><img src="sumo_button" ></a>
<!--{/if}-->
<!--{/if}-->
<!--▲HEADER-->
```

Could anyone tell me proper way of doing something like above?

Regarding above, if parts are not working, and always show the bottom button which is sumo_button.

Comment: Do you have any rewrite that interprets `usa.php` as `index.php?page=usa` ? In your code you are checking `page` parameter from get, but URL that you provided does not have any parameters.

Comment: Thnks for your comment. Since I want url to be as simple as possible I don't use any parameter such as you showed me, "xxxxx.com/usa.php" is the one I already decided the url to be, and in the situation like this I am wondering if there are any code that pick up or read some words such as "usa" from url with the way I tried above instead of using parameters. Do you know anything about it?